# Not Showing Image in ngx-image-zoom

Tags: angular, image, bootstrap-4, ngx-image-cropper

```
 <ngx-image-zoom [thumbImage]=imageString [fullImage]=imageString [magnification]="1"
        [enableScrollZoom]="true" [enableLens]="true" [lensWidth]="200"></ngx-image-zoom>

imageString  = "https://localhost:5101/DoImages/dced0609-1d03-4cd8-80ad-4ace5507e26d_fullres.jpg"
```

Im getting image clearly but its not showing in ngx-image-zoom control. already imported required library as "import { NgxImageZoomModule } from 'ngx-image-zoom';" in app.module.ts and also from component module but dist showing image? what wrong with above?

Comment: Please add snippets of your code to assist you better. May be a `StackBlitz`!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the tag to `lib-ngx-image-zoom` as stated in the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom#using-this-library).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30289345)